# Address operator and variable token joining macro

Tags: c

I have had a problem with running a program that (when simplified) looks something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ADDR_TOKEN_MACRO(x) & ## x
int main() {
    int *i;
    int **y;
    int b = 0xDEADBEEF;
    *y = ADDR_TOKEN_MACRO(b);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to set the integer pointer i's address to 0xDEADBEEF, but if I wanted to have the address be inputted by the user, I have come to the conclusion that this is the best way to do so.
However, I keep getting this error:

```
error: pasting "&" and "b" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

First of all, is the idea behind the program even possible in C?
And if the first question is true, can a macro like this be implemented?

Comment: You don’t need the `##` at all.

Comment: You don't need the macro at all.

Comment: In fact you don't want the user to input a memory address since the user can't possible know what a valid address for your program might be.

Answer (score 2):

Your macro is trying to take `&` and `b` and combine it into a single token `&b`.  This is not a valid identifier, so you can't do this.  What you want however is simpler than that:

```
#define ADDR_TOKEN_MACRO(x) &x
```

Now you have the address-of operator applied to the given token.

Actually, using a macro doesn't make much sense here at all.  You can just do this:

```
*y = &b;
```

This is a problem however because `y` was not assigned a value but you try to dereference `y`.  I think what you're **really** trying to do is:

```
int *i = (int *)0xDEADBEEF;
```

But then it's also questionable if you really want to do this, because the user shouldn't need to know anything about a specific address.